# JS Math - Get Var Val & Round to nearest 100th

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I am trying to get take a variable and pull the value from it to round it up to the nearest 100th. I am not certain what I am doing incorrectly.  Basically, I need it to come out looking like:

"103.19999999999999"  should round to "103.2"

"97.2333333333" should round to "97.24"

Here is the code:

```
JS
$sendAmount = "103.19999999999999";  //this can change based on user input. 

//Update the Amount
    function $convFee () {
        Math.ceil($sendAmount.val() * 100) / 100;
    };

    $input.keyup($convFee);
```

Comment: What are you getting?

Comment: use [`.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) instead.

Comment: @KevinBoucher 

I have tried using: Math.ceil(parseFloat($sendAmount) * 100) / 100;
and
Math.ceil(parseFloat($sendAmount.val()) * 100) / 100;

These did not work correctly.

Comment: @KevinBoucher 
I also just tried:  Math.ceil(parseFloat($sendAmount.val())).toFixed(2); 
and 
Math.ceil(parseFloat($sendAmount)).toFixed(2);

These are still returning a long string of numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a string `$sendAmount.val()` in your calculation.

You need this conversion:

```
 parseFloat($sendAmount.val())
```

Comment: I don't think this is the issue. He multiplies the value by `100` which should coerce that value into a `Number`.

Comment: This is what I ended up with (after adding some other calculations I needed):

$sendAmount.val(Math.ceil(parseFloat($userAmount.val() * 1.029 * 100) ) / 100 + 0.3);

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
103.19999999999999.toFixed(2) // "103.20"

97.2333333333.toFixed(2) // "97.23"
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is close:

`Math.ceil(97.2333333333 * 100) / 100;` = 97.24
and
`Math.ceil(103.19999999999999 * 100) / 100` = 103.2

So the error must be in the handling the variables.

It looks like `$sendAmount = "103.19999999999999";` is a string, but then your code calls `$sendAmount.val()` which will throw a typeError since `$sendAmount.val() is not a function`.

If you're taking in a string, you probably need to cast it to a float, like this:

```
$sendAmount = "103.19999999999999";  //taking in a string value for a float 

//Update the Amount
function $convFee () {
    Math.ceil(parseFloat($sendAmount) * 100) / 100; //convert to float, don't call .val() on string variable
};

$input.keyup($convFee);
```

Comment: This did not work exactly.  It did not cause errors to be thrown until I sent the information to Paypal.  They need a maximum of 2 decimal places.